# Better way of using logger in Golang?

Tags: function, go, methods

I am initialising a logger in my main application something like this.

```
----------main.go----------
package main
type AppServer struct {
    router *gin.Engine
    server *http.Server
    logger zerolog.Logger
}

func (app *AppServer) Init(pm zerolog.Logger) error {
   
    ........
    app.logger = pm
    //Here i am sending this logger to the service package
    services.Service.Init(pm)
    ..........
    return nil
}
```

Now i am saving this in a struct in my service.go file like this..

```
----------service.go----------

package services

................

var (
    Service serviceInterface = &service{}
)

type service struct {
    pm   zerolog.Logger
    path string
}

type serviceInterface interface {
    Init(zerolog.Logger) error
    p_man() (zerolog.Logger, error)
}
//This is called from main application to store that logger in this struct
func (s *service) Init(pm zerolog.Logger) error {
    s.pm = pm
    return nil
}
//Returningg the saved logger from struct
func (s *service) p_man() (zerolog.Logger, error) {
    
    return s.pm, nil
}
```

Now the first option i have is that, i can use it in other files with same package=services directly e.g.

```
----------1st option example1.go----------
package services

func (s *service) first() error {
    fmt.Println(s.pm)
    return nil
}
```

or using the function param_manager

```
----------2nd option example1.go----------
package services

func (s *service) 2nd() error {
    a,_:= Service.p_man()
    fmt.Println(a)
    return nil
}
```

I am confused about which is the right or better way of doing this? i would like to use the same logger in some other packages as well. So far i have a service package with different interfaces and if i use the 1st one then i have to define only one interface for all the functions and use the logger. And then for other packages i again have to init that in main.go for each package. Is the 2nd way better then 1st one? as i can import the package in other packages and use the function directly to get the logger?

Comment: I would suggest to go to 3rd option, take a look at https://medium.com/swlh/distributed-request-logging-in-go-with-context-api-16040688ed36 and https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2016/context-logging/

Comment: Hi Maxian, thanks alot for your suggestion it is quite helpful. But can you suggest if i have to take one from above what would be the better? i would like to use the same approach for other things as well then i will have a better idea how can i use a single initialised function from different packages. :)